# Last non NULL filling

Tags: sql-server

The problem is quite known, but I still can't find the perfect solution. I want to fill NULL in the column with last known value. The problem is that the table has more than 250 million rows, and existing solutions kill the server.

I found 2 solutions proposed by [Itzik Ben-Gan](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/last-non-null-puzzle). The first one still works for a long time, in the second one I get the error "**Error converting data type varbinary to numeric.**"

The table below shows the problem. Col1 contains NULLs, the effect I want to get is in the Final column.

[image]

Can anyone help?

Data for test

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1
(
  Date DATE NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_T1 PRIMARY KEY,
  col1 DECIMAL(18,6) NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.T1([date], col1) VALUES
  ( '2012-08-30', NULL),
  ( '2012-08-31',   10),
  ( '2012-09-01',   -1),
  ( '2012-09-02', NULL),
  ('2012-09-03', NULL),
  ('2012-09-04',  -12),
  ('2012-09-05', NULL),
  ('2012-09-06', NULL),
  ('2012-09-07', 1759);
```

The first solution works:

```
   WITH C AS
(
 SELECT Date
        ,col1
        ,relevantid,
        MAX(relevantid) OVER( ORDER BY Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) AS grp
 FROM dbo.T1
   CROSS APPLY ( VALUES( CASE WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL THEN Date END ) ) AS A(relevantid)
)
SELECT Date,col1
      ,MAX(col1) OVER( PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) AS Final
FROM C;
```

I have a problem with the second solution below.

Anyone know why it doesn't work?

```
SELECT  Date,
        col1,
        CAST(  SUBSTRING( MAX( CAST(date AS BINARY(4)) + CAST(col1 AS BINARY(4)) ) OVER( ORDER BY date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ),5, 4) AS DECIMAL(18,6)) AS lastval
FROM dbo.T1;
```

Comment: The error seems rather self explanatory?  Whatever the result is of `SUBSTRING( MAX( CAST(date AS BINARY(4)) + CAST(col1 AS BINARY(4)) ) OVER( ORDER BY date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ),5, 4)` is not able to be converted to numeric.  Maybe this will help: https://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=186457

Comment: My best guess is that you shouldn't `CAST` to binary.  I don't know what that line is trying to do.

Comment: In the CAST to Binary issue it is well explained in the article:
https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/last-non-null-puzzle
Generally, the example from the article works with solution # 2, the problem is when the values ​​are DECIMAL and not INT as in the example from the article.

Comment: Personally I would be wary with messing around with binary representations of decimal as [they don't have fixed size](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/184325/3690) - I normally use a human readable string with correct lexicographic ordering for this rather than binary

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find out where the problem was, maybe someone would be useful for the future.

```
SELECT  Date,
    col1,
    CAST(  SUBSTRING( MAX( CAST(CAST(date as DATETIME) AS BINARY(32)) + CAST(col1 AS BINARY(12)) ) OVER( ORDER BY date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ),33, 12) AS DECIMAL(18,6)) AS lastval
```

FROM dbo.T1;

Comment: This looks much wider than needed. `DATETIME` is 8 bytes so doesn't need 32 reserved